# Order of module in magento if located in same code pool and extend same core class

Tags: magento

I was wondering how the order of the modules decided if two or more modules are in same code pool and overwrite same core class. Any help would be appreciated as i couldnot find this googling for an hour now.

Comment: `<depends>` controls which module will be loaded first.

Comment: If there are two modules and no <depends> tag is used, which module will be loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - multiple classes extending same core class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501536/magento-multiple-classes-extending-same-core-class)

Comment: I have seen that post but what i need is not the solution. I know the solution of multiple overrides. What i need to know is in what order are they loaded? Is it alphabetical or something else?